# I'm not Understanding the IMGUR API

Tags: php, api, imgur

So I'm experimenting with the IMGUR API.

I created an "application" and got a client and secret id.

What I was hoping to do was to just retrieve the list of albums in my account. Sounds pretty simple. 
When I run the below PHP the response I get back is the IMGUR login page...although I'm logged into my account.

Maybe I'm not understanding how to get to the list of Albums in my account.

Any advice welcome on how to get the authorization then pass that back to get the actual access token to begin using the API.

```
<?


$client_secret = 'XXX';
$client_id = 'XXX';

const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize';
const ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token';
const REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE = 'code';
const APPLICATION_STATE='';

$query_data = array(
    'client_id'=> $client_id,
    'response_type'=>REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE,
    'state'=>APPLICATION_STATE
    );

$query_string = http_build_query($query_data);





$url = AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT.'?'.$query_string;
echo $url;

#$headers = array('Authorization: Client-ID $client_id');
#$pvars  = array('image' => base64_encode($file));

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL=> $url,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
 #  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
 #  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pvars
));

$json_returned = curl_exec($curl); // blank response
echo "Result: " . $json_returned ;
print_r( curl_getinfo($curl) );

curl_close ($curl);



?>
```

Comment: what's the documentation link to the imgur api endpoint you are using?

Comment: Imgur used [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/documentation/) for authentication. Firstly you need to send the request thru SSL with https, and you're currently not doing that. I expect this is the first thing that needs to get sorted.

Comment: fbas...I'm using https://api.imgur.com/oauth2 as the instructions...

Comment: Andrew...It is pointed to https:// URL that should be an HTTPS request then......

Answer (score 0):

The Authorize url needs to be visited by the user in an interactive session so they can grant permission to your app.  The documentation mentions that upon authorizing, they will be redirected to the url you specify in your app registration with a token for you to use.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand as the APP owner shouldn't I just be able to use it...that is where I'm missing things...